# Installing SharePoint to Root or Child domain

Tags: sharepoint, configuration, deployment

We're looking at deploying SharePoint within our company, and there's one question that I haven't been able to find any advice on. The enterprise is currently setup with a single root domain that is essentially empty, and several child domains for each of our major locations.

Our SharePoint deployment will only consist of a single SP server for the enterprise as the initial usage will be kept relatively small. A separate SQL Server used for the database.

What I haven't been able to figure out is what domain should the server be setup in? Does it matter? What about all the various service accounts? Do they need to be in the same domain as the server?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find any documentation how to do this? I've got my root domain and child domain but I can't seem to log in as child domain users. I wonder what step I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our SP environment is setup this way, all servers and service accounts reside in the root domain, but all actual users reside in 4 child domains. Depending on how many features you want to implement for users and the nature of security restrictions with AD trusts, firewalls, etc, you would have to open up several ports from the SP servers to child DCs and other resources.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can go as your hart contend. If all the domains are in the same forest, Or in other trust relationship, you can choose what ever looks best for you from administration point of view.

Comment: Thanks Igal. That's what I figured, but I haven't been able to find any documentation about it one way or another.